# Repository naming conventions for web application

Tags: git, web-applications, version-control, repository, naming-conventions

I have a web application that, like usual, is divided in two parts: server-side and client-side.

I like to work with international naming conventions for everything, and I've been trying to find some conventions on how to name my repositories.

What should I name my repositories on GitHub?

server-side - For the server-side application
client-side - For the client-side application

I've also hear someone say that the server-side repository should be called API.

Is that correct? What would you guys do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are developing an application which belongs together. The server and client side are related to each other. This means to me to have a single repository called "Application" which contains both server and client side.

Answer (score 3):

"server-side" and "client-side" sound great to me.

With naming conventions, if you have to think more than 1 minute about them, you're thinking too hard! Just name it so that it is self-explanatory & clear, especially to yourself -- no one else is going to care about this as much as you do. Besides, names can always be easily changed later.

Answer (score 0):

Project layout conventions vary between languages and build systems.

For example a simple java web app could look like this when using the Maven build system.

```
appname
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- java
        |   `-- com
        |       `-- company
        |           `-- appname
        |               `-- Controller.java
        `-- webapp
            `-- view.jsp
```

The `view.jsp` is the client side view and the `Controller.java` is the server side business logic.